# React native expo - can't fetch localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I'm building a React Native app with Expo, I'm trying to fetch my back-end server like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://192.168.1.89:8080/api/ciborg/groups')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.log("->>>>"+error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  });
```

But is always gives me the following error

> "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

I have already tried the following:

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.89:8080/api/ciborg/groups')
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/ciborg/groups')
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/ciborg/groups')
```

But it's always the same result. However fetching outside APIs like: https://reactnative.dev/movies.json works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you confirm that your server is up and running in port `8080` ?

Comment: Can you try a fetch with POSTMAN ?

Comment: (nodejs server)The code has:
app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port: 8080');
});

And in the console:
  Listening on port: 8080

The back-end recognises a "GET" requests, for example, but in the front-end it always catch and error.

And i can test well the back-end with postman requests and even if i, in the back-end (nodejs) side, create a web browser app to see the request i also can.

Answer (score 1):

I had a nodejs express server. And i added:

```
install-> npm install cors
Add to code: 
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

And it resolved my problem.